# Set default (selected) option Ember 1.13.11

Tags: ember.js

**Sort version:**

Why does this work: `<option disabled={{option.isSelected}}>`

But not this: `<option selected={{option.isSelected}}>`

**Long version:**

This is more about me learning how Ember works than about getting this working, since there are lots of working examples for this already.

I'm trying to set the default selected option in a select menu. It looks like there are different ways of doing this and that the recommended method is changing.

I'm working in Ember 1.13.11 but want to be Ember 2.0 compatible.

I haven't found a Ember 2.0 compatible method that didn't involve a template helper for the `selected` attribute. I can create a true/false value as a property on the controller. I know I'm doing it right because `disabled` works properly. Why does this fail only for `select`?

Template call:

```
{{version-details item=version status=version.status}}
```

Component controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'select',
  options: Ember.computed('status', function() {
    var statusOptions = ['beta', 'current', 'future', 'retired-beta', 'retired', 'unknown'];
    var selected = this.get('status');
    var optionsData = [];
    statusOptions.forEach( function(status){
      var isSelected = (selected == status);
      optionsData.push({ status: status, isSelected: isSelected });
    })
    return optionsData;
  }),
  setAction: '',
});
```

Component:

```
{{#each options as |option|}}
  <option selected={{option.isSelected}}>{{option.status}}</option>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Works for me. The status I pass in becomes the selected value. http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lezulo/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I've spent a lot of time banging into ember's select and just always use x-select now https://github.com/thefrontside/emberx-select.

Comment: @blessenm Argh! Thank yoooooou. I wonder if I was running into some kind of conflict between the selected default and the browser helpfully remembering what had been selected last time I viewed the from. Gave it a hard refresh and now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

As @blessenm points out. It does work.

I think couldn't tell it was working because the browser was remembering and selecting the value from the last time I visited the page.